# (JavaScript) Can't run two functions after eachother

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I was doing some Javascript and I made two functions after eachother but when I started typing the second one, the first one don't work anymore, but it did work before I type the second function.

My Code (Not finished yet, but I think that wouldn't make any difference):

```
var timeForSlide = 4000;
var slide1 = $('#Slide1');
var slide2 = $('#Slide2');
var slide3 = $('#Slide3');
var topPosition = slide1;

slide2.hide();
slide3.hide();
setInterval(changeSlide,timeForSlide);

function changeSlide(){  
    if (topPosition === slide1){
        slide1.fadeOut('fast');
        slide3.fadeIn('slow');
        topPosition = slide3;
    } else if (topPosition === slide3){
        slide3.fadeOut('fast');
        slide2.fadeIn('slow');
        topPosition = slide2;
    } else {
        slide2.fadeOut('fast');
        slide1.fadeIn('slow');
        topPosition = slide1;
    }
    };


function checkSlide(){
    alert("Checked");
    if (topPosition === slide1){
        $('#Circle_1').animate({backgroundColor: "gray"},'slow');   
    } else if (){

    } else {

    }
};

checkSlide();
```

And Yes I placed it in a `$(document).ready(function(){})`
But I couldn't copy all the code that will be to much.
So if somebody could explane this "bug" / "problem" how to do it right?

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: You should definitely add jquery tag to this question.

Comment: What about `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` in `} else if (){` line?

Comment: Consider adding a http://plnkr.co/edit/ (other js-buckets are available) to demonstrate the problem you are facing. Especially "animation-problems" tend to be difficult to figure out for others not directly involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be surprised that code that is not syntactically correct is rejected by the javascript interpreter. Complete your second function by adding a condition to the last `else if` and everything should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for rude answer oo yeah sorry I'm new at js, Simple thoughts right that if there is something in de if statement that it wil show right please greate forums over here

Comment: Didn't mean to be rude, just a bit sarcastic ;-) Anyway, if I answered your question, you could mark the anwer as correct by clicking the tick next to the vote counter.